# how to get first column value of selected row and to delete that selected row using jquery datatable

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

iam newbie to jquery.Iam working with jquery datatable plugin. I want to get the first column value of a selected row and after getting the value i need to make a ajax request. after the success of the ajax request i need to delete the row.

I tried the following code

```
var myjson='[{"isTruncated": "false","nextMarker": "null","marker": "null","prefix":   "Mymedia/mysys/","contents": [{"deviceInfo": "null","lastModified": "Thu Dec 26 16:36:42 IST 2013","etag": "d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e","key":"Mymedia/mysys/audio_$folder$","size": "0"},{"deviceInfo": null,"lastModified": "Thu Dec 26 16:36:11 IST 2013","etag": "d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e","key": "Mymedia/mysys/doc_$folder$","size": "0"},{ "deviceInfo": null,"lastModified": "Thu Dec 26 16:36:20 IST 2013", "etag": "d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e","key": "Mymedia/mysys/imge_$folder$","size": "0"},{"deviceInfo": null,"lastModified": "Thu Dec 26 16:36:56 IST 2013","etag": "d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e","key":"Mymedia/mysys/others_$folder$","size": "0"},{"deviceInfo": null,"lastModified": "Thu Dec 26 16:36:32 IST 2013","etag": "d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e","key": "Mymedia/mysys/video_$folder$","size": "0"}],"name": "name", "statusCode": "200","statusMessage": "Success","error": null}]';
```

Mytable [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNFR4.png)

if i click on deletesymbol in the table i need to get the first column value and i need to delete the row.

anyone help me out of this.

**IS THIS POSSIBLE WITH DATATABLE OR NOT???**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code is worked for me in getting first column value of a row selected in datatable plugin. here you can see delete_params and request_call which is a ajax-call to delete values from datatabase so you can avoid those codes.

```
 oTable = $('#example').dataTable({
                         "bDestroy": true,
                         "bPaginate": false,
                         "aaData": Listobj,
                         "bLengthChange": false,
                         "iDisplayLength": 10,
                         "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
                         "oTableTools": {
                             "sRowSelect": "single"
                         }
                     });

                     $('#example tr').click(function () {
                         $(this).toggleClass('row_selected');
                     });

                     $('#example tbody tr').live('click', function (event) {
                         var aData = oTable.fnGetData(this);
                         if (null != aData) {
                             var colun_data = aData[0];
                       /*****  var delete_params = { "objectName": colun_data
                             };
                             Request_Call(delete_params, Tablevalues_callback, delete_URL);******/
                         }
                         var anSelected = fnGetSelected(oTable);
                         if (anSelected.length !== 0) {
                             oTable.fnDeleteRow(anSelected[0]);
                         }
                     });

   function fnGetSelected(oTableLocal) {
        return oTableLocal.$('tr.row_selected');
 }
```